# Translating following piece of VB.NET code to Lambda/ LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

The presented piece of code is used to find missing records in very large data set. Let say *gA* represents record numbers of correct data set. Another application delivers *gB* data set, which record numbers are supposed to be identical to *gA*. Even the number of missing records is small (19 against total of 36886) it prevents me from further calculations. The whole utility is written in mix of *Lambda* and *LINQ* so want to convert it to look the same...

```
    Dim gA As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    Dim gB As New List(Of Integer) From {2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9}

    Dim rA, rB As Integer
    For Each recA As Integer In gA
        Dim recB As Integer = gB(rA)
        If recA = recB Then
            rA += 1
        Else
            rB += 1
            Console.WriteLine("{0} missing record: {1}", rB, recA)
        End If
    Next
    ' Output:
    '1 missing record: 1
    '2 missing record: 3
    '3 missing record: 8
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Translating following piece of VB.NET code to Lambda/ LINQ

Comment: What should the output be if `gB = From {8, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9}`?

Comment: Just something to consider...if the rest of the code is written with lambdas and linq but this part isn't, may want to think about if there's a reason for that before you change it. Linq doesn't perform as well on large datasets compared to a simple for loop, so if this operation is expensive, perhaps linq wasn't used intentionally. That said, all you really need is `gA.Except(gB)`, that will leave you with the numbers in A that are missing from B

Comment: The OP's code doesn't do what `gA.Except(gB)` will do.

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed  Obviously for simplicity, you may noticed, that both arrays are sorted in ascending order. Otherwise the function might be more complicated... After sorting {8, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9}  became { 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} and the missing items are {1,3}

Comment: @ soohoonigan Brilliant.  Thanks a lot. So simple!

Comment: @ATeDe, I realize from the beginning that you might be looking for the `Except` method. But I just wanted to point out that it will **not** check if the two lists are identical. For example, if you tried to compare `{1, 2, 3}` against `{2, 2, 3}`, your code would give a result that is not identical to what `Except()` would produce. Which one should be your expected behavior is up to you, of course :)

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed  I mentioned in my post all conditions for the presented case.  If the both data sets are identical there is no point to do anything else. Only if the numbers differ then I need to find out which records are corrupted and why, to I can repair them accordingly

Answer (score 4):

Seems you're looking fot [Enumerable.Except() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Dim gA As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
Dim gB As New List(Of Integer) From {2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9}
DIm diff = gA.Except(gB).ToList()
```

Above code produces a list of `Integers`: `{1, 3, 8}`

Comment: `Except()` method doesn't do what the OP's code does. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359272/translating-following-piece-of-vb-net-code-to-lambda-linq#comment87735475_50359272).

Comment: Yes, actually it does. You end up with a collection of {1, 3, 8}. All that's left is to iterate it and write it to console, and he no longer needs rA and rB counts because those can be inferred from the new collection's count.

Comment: @soohoonigan, It might actually be what the OP is trying to achieve, but it **does Not** do what the code in the question does. Run the both methods for `gB = From {8, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9}` and let me know if the results are identical.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, As my predecessor said, it does. Op is looking for missing records - as far as i understand his question. BTW: He does not need exact code translation. He needs to get desired result.

Comment: I started my previous comment saying _"It might actually be what the OP is trying to achieve"_. However, based on the code in the question. The two behaviors are not identical. That's all I wanted to point out.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, my logic is to answer exact question. am not authorized to solve problems that were not found in the question.

Comment: I have no problem with that logic actually :) I just wanted to point that out because if it wasn't what the OP is looking for, he might think it does what he wants and never finds out until later stages. That's all :)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, Ok. I understand your point of view, but it does not change mine. ;) Best regards, Maciej.

Comment: How I said my VB function works only on sorted arrays. So pretending (@AhmedAbdelhameed) other scenarios is pointless

Comment: @ATeDe until it's not sorted... then it's broke. Hey, it's just a little technical debt for the next guy to suffer over.

Comment: Besides, if I'm understanding completely, this is part of refactoring. If you change code that works into something that does "close" to what that one does, but not exactly, I wouldn't expect it to pass a code review. The new Lambda code should do the same thing the current code is doing or something dependent upon this will fail.

Comment: @Mikejg101 The little routine I've presented was a quick (1 minute) fix, to get a missing records,  on the assumption that both arrays are sorted.  It's simple and is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

The simple "translation" would be:

```
var gA = new List<Int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
var gB = new List<Int>() { 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9 };

int rA, rB;

gA.ForEach(recA =>
{
    gB.ForEach(recB =>
    {
        if (recA == recB)
        {
            rA++;
        }
        else
        {
            rB++;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} missing record: {1}", rB, recA);
        }
    });
})
```

However another approach would be using `Contains`

```
gA.ForEach(recA =>
{
    if (gB.Contains(recA))
    {
        rA++;
    }
    else
    {
        rB++;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} missing record: {1}", rB, recA);
    }
})
```

Finally a cleaner and more concise option is using `Except` and a `ForEach` in the resulting collection.

```
gA.Except(gB).ForEach((item, idx) => Console.WriteLine("{0} missing record: {1}", idx, item));
```

Comment: Final solution deserves for upvote, even if i think that OP does not need exact "translation".

Comment: I agree with you, I do prefer the final approach, but it never hurts to have options.

Comment: J. Pichardo  OK thanks, Actually word "translation" in the title of this post was quite inappropriate what @soohoonigan picked  up very intelligently  from the beginning and suggested the simplest solution using Except() method. Best regards!

Comment: This is C#. You can't drop a bit of C# into a vb file.